# Paypal not integrating into Twitter-Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, paypal

I'm working on a Twitter-Bootstrap site that is using a Paypal Donate button. It seems like it is having an integration issue. The button shows up on the page, but it does't do anything when clicked - other than initiate a "Message Sent" pop up from the contact form immediately preceding it.

I have checked with the host, and everything is go from there. I checked with Paypal and they said the code is working. They referred me to one of their specialists who said that the code needed a  at the beginning of the code to unwrap it from the rest of the page. I made that edit, but it's still not working and the specialist hasn't gotten back to me. Can someone explain what the problem is and how to fix it? The site is at http://africanbn.org/

HTML

```
        </form> <!-- Unwraps Paypal to Allow Processing -->
            <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="PayPal">  
                <input name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" type="hidden">  
                <input name="hosted_button_id" value="8AGYNX8B7PGSQ" type="hidden">
                <input src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="        PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" border="0" type="image">
                <img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" height="1" border="0" width="1">
             </form>
```

Comment: so basically whats not working, does the form doesn't take you to paypal? does it gives you any error, any paypal required parameter missing?

Comment: When clicked, it doesn't redirect to paypal. Strangely, it initiates a 'Message Sent' pop up in the contact form located just before it.

Comment: if you take page source view, you can see two `</form>` , one at line 736 and other at line 753, delete the one at line 753,

Comment: The second one was the solution recommended by Paypal - although it didn't work. I will delete it, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 3):

You have another form above it that it is conflicting with. When the Paypal button is clicked, your contact form submits as well.

Comment: So how can I fix it? I need both forms.

Comment: If you want to fix the problem, you have to first figure out why the act of clicking the paypal button would submit your contact form button - in other words, they are two of the same action. Find the similarities, and differentiate them so they are no longer the same action.

Comment: Another solution: you could just make your own Paypal button and use an href tag to link to the specified page.